# Chrome Extension Event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does chrome emits an event whenever a new extension is installed in chrome? If yes, how to listen to this event. 
  I want to know somehow that the user has installed an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [`chrome.management.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#event-onInstalled), don't forget `management` permission

Comment: Do we need to give permission to unlock the management API? If yes, I am looking for something which can be used for any user of chrome, not just for development.

Comment: @AmanGupta, just declare `management` for `permissions` field in `manifest.json`, that's all you need to do and it applies for any user of chrome.

Comment: Ok will do that. So I need to attach an event to above inside content script of the extension

Comment: @AmanGupta, no, you need to put it in background page, content scripts are not allowed to access this api.